# Bootstrap Accordion - Only one open at a time

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I got a problem with the Bootstrap accordion. I can't get it to only open one at a time! I feel like I've tried everything! I know I have changed the structure so that the panel-body appears under the panel-headings, but shouldn't that be possible?

Hope anyone is able to help! Thanks in advance!

[fænøpark.dk/lokaler-3](http://f%C3%A6n%C3%B8park.dk/lokaler-3) This is the page I'm trying to add this on!

```html
<h1>Oversigt over lokaler</h1>
 <div id="accordion" class="panel-group">
<div class="col-md-4">

  <div class="panel panel-default">
   <div id="headingOne" role="tab" class="panel-heading">
   <p class="panel-title collapsed"><a class="lokalepanel" role="botton" href="#collapseOne" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" aria-controls="collapseOne" aria-expanded="false">• Fænø – Op til 80 pers. (Tryk for at læse mere)</a></p>
   </div>

  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
   <div id="headingTwo" role="tab" class="panel-heading">
   <p class="panel-title collapsed"><a class="lokalepanel" role="botton" href="#collapseTwo" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" aria-controls="collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false">• Fænø Sund – Op til 54 pers. (Tryk for at læse mere)</a></p>
   </div>

  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
   <div id="headingThree" role="tab" class="panel-heading">
   <p class="panel-title"><a class="lokalepanel" href="#collapseThree" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">• Fænø Kalv – Op til 50 pers. (Tryk for at læse mere)</a></p>
   </div>

  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
   <div id="headingFour" class="panel-heading">
   <p class="panel-title"><a class="lokalepanel" href="#collapseFour" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">• Teglgård – Op til 50 pers. (Tryk for at læse mere)</a></p>
   </div>

  </div>
 
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">

  <div class="panel panel-default">
   <div id="headingFive" class="panel-heading">
   <p class="panel-title"><a class="lokalepanel" href="#collapseFive" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">• Vejlby Strand – Op til 50 pers. (Tryk for at læse mere)</a></p>
   </div>

  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
   <div id="headingSix" class="panel-heading">
   <p class="panel-title"><a class="lokalepanel" href="#collapseSix" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">• Gamborg – Op til 30 pers. (Tryk for at læse mere)</a></p>
   </div>

  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
   <div id="headingSeven" class="panel-heading">
   <p class="panel-title"><a class="lokalepanel" href="#collapseSeven" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">• Gl. Havn – Op til 40 pers. (Tryk for at læse mere)</a></p>
   </div>

  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
   <div id="headingEight" class="panel-heading">
   <p class="panel-title"><a class="lokalepanel" href="#collapseEight" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">• Lillebælt – Op til 200 pers. (Tryk for at læse mere)</a></p>
   </div>

  </div>

</div>
<div class="col-md-4">

  <div class="panel panel-default">
   <div id="headingNine" class="panel-heading">
   <p class="panel-title"><a class="lokalepanel" href="#collapseNine" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">• Slugten – Op til 16 pers. (Tryk for at læse mere)</a></p>
   </div>

  </div>
  <p><strong>Restaurant lokaler</strong></p>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
   <div id="headingTen" class="panel-heading">
   <p class="panel-title"><a class="lokalepanel" href="#collapseTen" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">• Gals Klint – Op til 72 pers. (Tryk for at læse mere)</a></p>
   </div>

  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
   <div id="headingTwelve" class="panel-heading">
   <p class="panel-title"><a class="lokalepanel" href="#collapseTwelve" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">• Røjle Klint – Op til 112 pers. (Tryk for at læse mere)</a></p>
   </div>

  </div>

</div>
   <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
    <div class="panel-body">
     <h2>Fænø – Op til 80 pers.</h2>
     [separator style_type="none" top_margin="" bottom_margin="10" sep_color="" icon="" width="" class="" id=""]
     <div class="col-md-4"><a href="http://fænøpark.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Faenoe-1024x768.jpg" target="_self" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery_image_1]"><img src="http://fænøpark.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Faenoe-1024x768.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
     <div class="col-md-4"><a href="http://fænøpark.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Faenoe3-1024x768.jpg" target="_self" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery_image_2]"><img src="http://fænøpark.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Faenoe3-1024x768.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
     <div class="col-md-4"><a href="http://fænøpark.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Faenoe2-1024x768.jpg" target="_self" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery_image_3]"><img src="http://fænøpark.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Faenoe2-1024x768.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
     [separator style_type="none" top_margin="" bottom_margin="20" sep_color="" icon="" width="" class="" id=""]
     <div class="fusion-table table-1">
     <table width="100%">
     <tbody>
     <tr>
     <td><strong>Lokalenavn</strong></td>
     <td>Fænø</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><strong>m2</strong></td>
     <td>115</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><strong>Mål</strong></td>
     <td>13,5 x 8,5</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><strong>Biograf</strong></td>
     <td>80 pers.</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><strong>Skole</strong></td>
     <td>60 pers.</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><strong>Sildeben</strong></td>
     <td>60 pers.</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><strong>U-Bord</strong></td>
     <td>32 pers.</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><strong>Cafe (6 pers.)</strong></td>
     <td>54 pers.</td>
     </tr>
     </tbody>
     </table>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
    <div class="panel-body">
     <h2>Fænø Sund – Op til 54 pers.</h2>
     [separator style_type="none" top_margin="" bottom_margin="10" sep_color="" icon="" width="" class="" id=""]
     <div class="col-md-4"><a href="http://fænøpark.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/FaenoeSund-1024x768.jpg" target="_self" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery_image_4]"><img src="http://fænøpark.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/FaenoeSund-1024x768.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
     <div class="col-md-4"><a href="http://fænøpark.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/FaenoeSund3-1024x768.jpg" target="_self" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery_image_5]"><img src="http://fænøpark.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/FaenoeSund2-1024x768.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
     <div class="col-md-4"><a href="http://fænøpark.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/FaenoeSund2-1024x768.jpg" target="_self" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery_image_6]"><img src="http://fænøpark.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/FaenoeSund3-1024x768.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
     [separator style_type="none" top_margin="" bottom_margin="20" sep_color="" icon="" width="" class="" id=""]
     <div class="fusion-table table-1">
     <table width="100%">
     <tbody>
     <tr>
     <td><strong>Lokalenavn</strong></td>
     <td>Fænø Sund</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><strong>m2</strong></td>
     <td>72</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><strong>Mål</strong></td>
     <td>8,5 x 8,5</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><strong>Biograf</strong></td>
     <td>54 pers.</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><strong>Skole</strong></td>
     <td>30 pers.</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><strong>Sildeben</strong></td>
     <td>30 pers.</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><strong>U-Bord</strong></td>
     <td>20 pers.</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><strong>Cafe (6 pers.)</strong></td>
     <td>30 pers.</td>
     </tr>
     </tbody>
     </table>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <div class="panel-body">
     <h2>Fænø Kalv – Op til 50 pers.</h2>
     [separator style_type="none" top_margin="" bottom_margin="10" sep_color="" icon="" width="" class="" id=""]
     <div class="col-md-4"><a href="http://fænøpark.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/FaenoeKalv-1024x768.jpg" target="_self" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery_image_7]"><img src="http://fænøpark.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/FaenoeKalv-1024x768.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
     <div class="col-md-4"><a href="http://fænøpark.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/FaenoeKalv2-1024x768.jpg" target="_self" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery_image_8]"><img src="http://fænøpark.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/FaenoeKalv2-1024x768.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
     <div class="col-md-4"><a href="http://fænøpark.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/FaenoeKalv3-1024x768.jpg" target="_self" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery_image_9]"><img src="http://fænøpark.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/FaenoeKalv3-1024x768.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
     [separator style_type="none" top_margin="" bottom_margin="20" sep_color="" icon="" width="" class="" id=""]
     <div class="fusion-table table-1">
     <table width="100%">
     <tbody>
     <tr>
     <td><strong>Lokalenavn</strong></td>
     <td>Fænø Kalv</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><strong>m2</strong></td>
     <td>72</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><strong>Mål</strong></td>
     <td>8,5 x 8,5</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><strong>Biograf</strong></td>
     <td>50 pers.</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><strong>Skole</strong></td>
     <td>40 pers.</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><strong>Sildeben</strong></td>
     <td>40 pers.</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><strong>U-Bord</strong></td>
     <td>24 pers.</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><strong>Cafe (6 pers.)</strong></td>
     <td>36 pers.</td>
     </tr>
     </tbody>
     </table>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div id="collapseFour" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <div class="panel-body">
     <h2>Teglgård – Op til 50 pers.</h2>
     [separator style_type="none" top_margin="" bottom_margin="10" sep_color="" icon="" width="" class="" id=""]
     <div class="col-md-4"><a href="http://fænøpark.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Teglgaard-1024x768.jpg" target="_self" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery_image_10]"><img src="http://fænøpark.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Teglgaard-1024x768.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
     <div class="col-md-4"><a href="http://fænøpark.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Teglgaard2-1024x768.jpg" target="_self" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery_image_11]"><img src="http://fænøpark.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Teglgaard2-1024x768.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
     <div class="col-md-4"><a href="http://fænøpark.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Teglgaard3-1024x768.jpg" target="_self" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery_image_12]"><img src="http://fænøpark.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Teglgaard3-1024x768.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
     [separator style_type="none" top_margin="" bottom_margin="20" sep_color="" icon="" width="" class="" id=""]
     <div class="fusion-table table-1">
     <table width="100%">
     <tbody>
     <tr>
     <td><strong>Lokalenavn</strong></td>
     <td>Teglgård</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><strong>m2</strong></td>
     <td>72</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><strong>Mål</strong></td>
     <td>8,5 x 8,5</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><strong>Biograf</strong></td>
     <td>50 pers.</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><strong>Skole</strong></td>
     <td>40 pers.</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><strong>Sildeben</strong></td>
     <td>32 pers.</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><strong>U-Bord</strong></td>
     <td>28 pers.</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><strong>Cafe (6 pers.)</strong></td>
     <td>36 pers.</td>
     </tr>
     </tbody>
     </table>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div id="collapseFive" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <div class="panel-body">
     <h2>Vejlby Stand – Op til 50 pers.</h2>
     [separator style_type="none" top_margin="" bottom_margin="10" sep_color="" icon="" width="" class="" id=""]
     <div class="col-md-4"><a href="http://fænøpark.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Vejlby-1024x768.jpg" target="_self" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery_image_13]"><img src="http://fænøpark.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Vejlby-1024x768.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
     <div class="col-md-4"><a href="http://fænøpark.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Vejlby2-1024x768.jpg" target="_self" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery_image_14]"><img src="http://fænøpark.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Vejlby2-1024x768.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
     <div class="col-md-4"><a href="http://fænøpark.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Vejlby3-1024x768.jpg" target="_self" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery_image_15]"><img src="http://fænøpark.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Vejlby3-1024x768.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
     [separator style_type="none" top_margin="" bottom_margin="20" sep_color="" icon="" width="" class="" id=""]
     <div class="fusion-table table-1">
     <table width="100%">
     <tbody>
     <tr>
     <td><strong>Lokalenavn</strong></td>
     <td>Vejlby Strand</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><strong>m2</strong></td>
     <td>72</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><strong>Mål</strong></td>
     <td>8,5 x 8,5</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><strong>Biograf</strong></td>
     <td>60 pers.</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><strong>Skole</strong></td>
     <td>48 pers.</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><strong>Sildeben</strong></td>
     <td>40 pers.</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><strong>U-Bord</strong></td>
     <td>26 pers.</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><strong>Cafe (6 pers.)</strong></td>
     <td>36 pers.</td>
     </tr>
     </tbody>
     </table>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div> 
   <div id="collapseSix" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <div class="panel-body">
     <h2>Gamborg – Op til 30 pers.</h2>
     [separator style_type="none" top_margin="" bottom_margin="10" sep_color="" icon="" width="" class="" id=""]
     <div class="col-md-4"><a href="http://fænøpark.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Gamborg-1024x768.jpg" target="_self" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery_image_16]"><img src="http://fænøpark.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Gamborg-1024x768.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
     <div class="col-md-4"><a href="http://fænøpark.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Gamborg2-1024x768.jpg" target="_self" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery_image_17]"><img src="http://fænøpark.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Gamborg2-1024x768.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
     <div class="col-md-4"><a href="http://fænøpark.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Gamborg3-1024x768.jpg" target="_self" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery_image_18]"><img src="http://fænøpark.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Gamborg3-1024x768.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
     [separator style_type="none" top_margin="" bottom_margin="20" sep_color="" icon="" width="" class="" id=""]
     <div class="fusion-table table-1">
     <table width="100%">
     <tbody>
     <tr>
     <td><strong>Lokalenavn</strong></td>
     <td>Gamborg</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><strong>m2</strong></td>
     <td>89</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><strong>Mål</strong></td>
     <td>10,5 x 8,5</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><strong>Biograf</strong></td>
     <td>30 pers.</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><strong>Skole</strong></td>
     <td>32 pers.</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><strong>Sildeben</strong></td>
     <td>32 pers.</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><strong>U-Bord</strong></td>
     <td>22 pers.</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><strong>Cafe (6 pers.)</strong></td>
     <td>30 pers.</td>
     </tr>
     </tbody>
     </table>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div> 
   <div id="collapseSeven" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <div class="panel-body">
    <h2>Gl. Havn – Op til 40 pers.</h2>
    [separator style_type="none" top_margin="" bottom_margin="10" sep_color="" icon="" width="" class="" id=""]
    <div class="col-md-4"><a href="http://fænøpark.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/GlHavn-1024x768.jpg" target="_self" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery_image_19]"><img src="http://fænøpark.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/GlHavn-1024x768.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"><a href="http://fænøpark.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/GlHavn2-1024x768.jpg" target="_self" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery_image_20]"><img src="http://fænøpark.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/GlHavn2-1024x768.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"><a href="http://fænøpark.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/GlHavn3-1024x768.jpg" target="_self" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery_image_21]"><img src="http://fænøpark.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/GlHavn3-1024x768.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
    [separator style_type="none" top_margin="" bottom_margin="20" sep_color="" icon="" width="" class="" id=""]
     <div class="fusion-table table-1">
     <table width="100%">
     <tbody>
     <tr>
     <td><strong>Lokalenavn</strong></td>
     <td>Gl. Havn</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><strong>m2</strong></td>
     <td>55</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><strong>Mål</strong></td>
     <td>8,7 x 6,25</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><strong>Biograf</strong></td>
     <td>40 pers.</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><strong>Skole</strong></td>
     <td>32 pers.</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><strong>Sildeben</strong></td>
     <td>32 pers.</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><strong>U-Bord</strong></td>
     <td>22 pers.</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><strong>Cafe (6 pers.)</strong></td>
     <td>36 pers.</td>
     </tr>
     </tbody>
     </table>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div id="collapseEight" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <div class="panel-body">
     <h2>Lillebælt - Op til 200 pers.</h2>
     [separator style_type="none" top_margin="" bottom_margin="10" sep_color="" icon="" width="" class="" id=""]
     <div class="col-md-4"><a href="http://fænøpark.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Lillebaelt-1024x768.jpg" target="_self" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery_image_22]"><img src="http://fænøpark.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Lillebaelt-1024x768.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
     <div class="col-md-4"><a href="http://fænøpark.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Lillebaelt2-1024x768.jpg" target="_self" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery_image_23]"><img src="http://fænøpark.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Lillebaelt2-1024x768.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
     <div class="col-md-4"><a href="http://fænøpark.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Lillebaelt3-1024x768.jpg" target="_self" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery_image_24]"><img src="http://fænøpark.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Lillebaelt3-1024x768.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
     [separator style_type="none" top_margin="" bottom_margin="20" sep_color="" icon="" width="" class="" id=""]
     <div class="fusion-table table-1">
     <table width="100%">
     <tbody>
     <tr>
     <td><strong>Lokalenavn</strong></td>
     <td>Lillebælt</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><strong>m2</strong></td>
     <td>183</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><strong>Mål</strong></td>
     <td>21,5 x 8,5</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><strong>Biograf</strong></td>
     <td>200 pers.</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><strong>Skole</strong></td>
     <td>160 pers.</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><strong>Sildeben</strong></td>
     <td>150 pers.</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><strong>U-Bord</strong></td>
     <td>50 pers.</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><strong>Cafe (6 pers.)</strong></td>
     <td>96 pers.</td>
     </tr>
     </tbody>
     </table>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div> 
   <div id="collapseNine" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <div class="panel-body">
     <h2>Slugten - Op til 16 pers.</h2>
     [separator style_type="none" top_margin="" bottom_margin="10" sep_color="" icon="" width="" class="" id=""]
     <div class="col-md-4"><a href="http://fænøpark.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Slugten-1024x768.jpg" target="_self" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery_image_25]"><img src="http://fænøpark.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Slugten-1024x768.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
     <div class="col-md-4"><a href="http://fænøpark.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Slugten2-1024x768.jpg" target="_self" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery_image_26]"><img src="http://fænøpark.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Slugten2-1024x768.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
     <div class="col-md-4"><a href="http://fænøpark.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Slugten3-1024x768.jpg" target="_self" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery_image_27]"><img src="http://fænøpark.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Slugten3-1024x768.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
     [separator style_type="none" top_margin="" bottom_margin="20" sep_color="" icon="" width="" class="" id=""]
     <div class="fusion-table table-1">
     <table width="100%">
     <tbody>
     <tr>
     <td><strong>Cafe (8 pers.)</strong></td>
     <td>16 pers.</td>
     </tr>
     </tbody>
     </table>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div id="collapseTen" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <div class="panel-body">
     <h2>Gals Klint - Op til 72 pers.</h2>
     [separator style_type="none" top_margin="" bottom_margin="10" sep_color="" icon="" width="" class="" id=""]
     <div class="col-md-4"><a href="http://fænøpark.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/GalsKlint-1024x768.jpg" target="_self" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery_image_28]"><img src="http://fænøpark.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/GalsKlint-1024x768.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
     <div class="col-md-4"><a href="http://fænøpark.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/GalsKlint2-1024x768.jpg" target="_self" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery_image_29]"><img src="http://fænøpark.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/GalsKlint2-1024x768.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
     <div class="col-md-4"><a href="http://fænøpark.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/GalsKlint3-1024x768.jpg" target="_self" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery_image_30]"><img src="http://fænøpark.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/GalsKlint3-1024x768.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
     [separator style_type="none" top_margin="" bottom_margin="20" sep_color="" icon="" width="" class="" id=""]
     <div class="fusion-table table-1">
     <table width="100%">
     <tbody>
     <tr>
     <td><strong>Lokalenavn</strong></td>
     <td>Gals Klint</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><strong>m2</strong></td>
     <td>164</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><strong>Mål</strong></td>
     <td>12,5 x 13,1</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><strong>U-Bord</strong></td>
     <td>46 pers.</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><b>E-Bord</b></td>
     <td>48 pers.</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><b>Rund (8 pers.)</b></td>
     <td>64 pers.</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><b>Rund (10 pers.)</b></td>
     <td>60 pers.</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><b>Cafe (8 pers.)</b></td>
     <td>64 pers.</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><b>Cafe (12 pers.)</b></td>
     <td>72 pers.</td>
     </tr>
     </tbody>
     </table>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div id="collapseTwelve" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <div class="panel-body">
     <h2>Røjle Klint - Op til 112 pers.</h2>
     [separator style_type="none" top_margin="" bottom_margin="10" sep_color="" icon="" width="" class="" id=""]
     <div class="col-md-4"><a href="http://fænøpark.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/RoejleKlint-1024x768.jpg" target="_self" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery_image_31]"><img src="http://fænøpark.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/RoejleKlint-1024x768.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
     <div class="col-md-4"><a href="http://fænøpark.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/RoejleKlint2-1024x768.jpg" target="_self" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery_image_32]"><img src="http://fænøpark.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/RoejleKlint2-1024x768.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
     <div class="col-md-4"><a href="http://fænøpark.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/RoejleKlint3-1024x768.jpg" target="_self" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery_image_33]"><img src="http://fænøpark.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/RoejleKlint3-1024x768.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
     [separator style_type="none" top_margin="" bottom_margin="20" sep_color="" icon="" width="" class="" id=""]
     <div class="fusion-table table-1">
     <table width="100%">
     <tbody>
     <tr>
     <td><strong>Lokalenavn</strong></td>
     <td>Røjle Klint</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><strong>m2</strong></td>
     <td>200</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><strong>Mål</strong></td>
     <td>23,5 x 8,5</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><strong>U-Bord</strong></td>
     <td>46 pers.</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><b>E-Bord</b></td>
     <td>54 pers.</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><b>Rund (8 pers.)</b></td>
     <td>72 pers.</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><b>Rund (10 pers.)</b></td>
     <td>90 pers.</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><b>Cafe (8 pers.)</b></td>
     <td>112 pers.</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><b>Cafe (12 pers.)</b></td>
     <td>108 pers.</td>
     </tr>
     </tbody>
     </table>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Just playing around with this and it doesn't look like you can just move the tabpanels to another location.  I simplified the file a bit (removed all but three panels), and it just doesn't work unless the tabpanels immediately follow the associated panel.  The way you have it layed out is NOT an accordion, so it is breaking what accordion knows how to do.  You could do this without much trouble by just using jquery/javascript -- on click of the button, hide all of the content divs and show the div associated with the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the tabpanels are not immediately under the controlling tab, the accordion functionality is broken.  A very hacky fix, following, is to add the following script, which will simply hide all of the panel-bodies and then show the correct one when one of the tabs is clicked.

```
<script>
    $( ".lokalepanel" ).click(function() {
        $(".panel-body").hide();
        var tgt = $(this).context.hash;
        $(tgt).show();
        $(tgt).children().show();
    });
</script>
```